# Как определить в Entity Framework, что модель не соответствует подключенной базе данных

Tags: entity-framework

Создал модель на основе базы данных. На сервере имеются несколько идентичных ей. Пользователь имеет возможность выбора к какой базе подключиться. Но в тоже время возникает проблема, что пользователь выберет иную БД, в которой отсутствуют требуемые таблицы и возникнет ошибка.
Как можно определить присутствуют ли в выбранной БД требуемые таблицы? Есть ли в Entity Framework для этого средства?

Использовал Database First

Comment: Вариант решения, не требующий глубоких знаний EF (посему не ответ). Выполнить любой простейший запрос обернув его в try/catch. Если ловится исключение которое должно возникать когда модель не соответствует схеме БД, говорить пользователю что туда нельзя.

Comment: А можете уточнить про используемый подход? Если нужен CodeFirst, то ответ @QodirbekMakharov идеален в силу простоты. Если DBFirst, то тут сложней, но могу предложить варианты.

Answer (score 9):

Если CodeFirst:

```
bool isCompatible = db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true);
```

true - модель и бд идентичны, false - модель и бд не идентичны.

Answer (score 5):

Таких встроенных средств в EF не нашел.
Но мой вариант решения такой

1. Включаем для БД контекста возможность миграций. Для этого вводим команду

   ```
   enable-migrations
   ```

из

> Tools → Library Package Manager → Package Manager Console

После выполнения команды в выбранном проекте должна создаться папка *Migrations*, а внутри этой папки файл *Configuration.cs*, который содержит настройки миграции.
В конструкторе этого автоматически сгенерированного класса отключаем автоматическую миграцию, установив свойству [AutomaticMigrationsEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.automaticmigrationsenabled(v=vs.113).aspx) значение `false`. Например,

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```

Теперь, при инициализации контекста БД, если схема БД не подходит описанной модели, то будет кидаться исключение(без попытки подстроить схему БД под модель).

[Выполняем явную инициализацию контекста](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.initialize(v=vs.113).aspx), завернув его в try/catch

```
try
{
   using(var context = new MyDb())
  {
      context.Database.Initialize(false);
  }
  // БД подходит под модель
}
catch
{
  // бд не соответствует схеме
}
```

Этот код можно завернуть в некий метод, возвращающий булево значение с результатом проверки соответствия модели и схемы БД.
Если возникло исключение, то значит схема БД не соответствует модели.

2. Также можно выполнить sql-скрипт для проверки существования в базе таблицы с помощью БД контекста:

   ```
   using(var dbContext = new MyDb())
   {
      int result = (dbContext as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(@"
      IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'TableName') 
          SELECT 1
      ELSE
          SELECT 0
      ").SingleOrDefault();
   }
   ```

Comment: [A K](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k) просил передать вам 50 очков репутации. :)

Comment: спасибо доброму человеку :)